# Reading Firebase child by auto ID swift

Tags: swift, firebase

This is a quick output of my Firebase tree, id like to access people_on_this_planit / userID node. My only issue is that node is within an auto ID; please any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
  planits
 -LEmgxuG_13KNA5inRaB
     Planit Title: "Some title"
     people_on_planit
      -LEmh6IxqguVBJEwghZv (auto ID)
         userID: "kkdiEW0D9"
     senderId: "39FdLfdIO8832"
```

Right now the code i am using is as follows, but i am getting nil when i print peopleonplanit.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid       
let planitsRef = ref.child("planits")

for child in snapshot.children {

    let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
    let dict = childSnap.value as! NSDictionary
    let planKey = childSnap.key
    //print(planKey)

    print(dict)


    let title = dict["Planit Title"] as! String
    let senderID = dict["senderId"] as! String
    let peopleOnPlanit = dict["people_on_planit"] as? String

    print(peopleOnPlanit)
}
```

Comment: Okay. Answer a question: _do you think the `value` in the key `"people_on_planit"` is a `String`?_ It is again a dictionary. And don't use `NS` prefixed types in swift

Comment: Oh yes, wow i see where my mistake lies at. I am treating it as a string instead of dictionary. wow. thank you

Comment: and swift is making me use NSDictionary here. Using normal dictionary i get an error

Comment: What did you use instead of `NSDictionary`?

Comment: i tried to put just Dictionary

Comment: Nope! The equivalent for `NSDictionary` in swift is `[String : Any]`

Comment: i actually get an error now @nayem

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and '[String : Any]'

Comment: On the line   if userID == peopleOnPlanit || userID == senderID{ }

Comment: I am referencing userID like - let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

Comment: i guess my main question is how do i pull out the userID within that node ? can i transform it to a string so that i can use it in an if statement where the value i am comparing it to is a string and not a dictionary @nayem

Comment: The child value of *dict["people_on_planit"] as? String* isn't a string according to your structure. It's actually a snapshot with a key of *LEmh6IxqguVBJEwghZv* but then it's value are child snapshots with key: value pairs of an autoId as the key and then a value of another key: value pair of *userID: "kkdiEW0D9"* (a String: String). What you need to do is to treat the *people_on_planit* as a key and then iterate over it's child nodes (the users) to read them in - similar to how you are handling in the *planitsRef* by iterating over it's child nodes. I can post code if needed, let me know.

Comment: @Jay ah! That makes sense when you lay it out that way. That’s why I couldn’t access just the actual value in the key:value pair userID: “kkdiWOD9”.. which is what I actually need.. could you please post the code if possible for more clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code to read the Firebase structure proposed in the question

```
let planitsRef = self.ref.child("planits")
planitsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    for child in snapshot.children {
        let planSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let planDict = planSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let title = planDict["plan_title"] as! String
        let senderId = planDict["sender_id"] as! String
        print("plan title: \(title)  senderId: \(senderId)")
        let peopleOnPlanitSnap = planSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "people_on_planit")

        for peopleChild in peopleOnPlanitSnap.children {
            let peopleChildSnap = peopleChild as! DataSnapshot
            let userSnapDict = peopleChildSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let userId = userSnapDict["user_id"] as! String
            print("  userId: \(userId)")
        }
    }
})
```

and the output

```
plan title: Some title  senderId: 39FdLfdIO8832
  userId: uid_0
  userId: uid_1
```

-- A couple of notes --

Since the associated users appear to be stored by their user Id and that's the only data stored within that node, you may want to change this node

```
people_on_planit
      -LEmh6IxqguVBJEwghZv (auto ID)
         userID: "kkdiEW0D9"
```

to look like this

```
people_on_planit
   uid_x: true //uid_x would be kkdiEW0D9 etc
   uid_y: true
```

it's a bit shallower and cleaner and requires less code to read it. Also, you can query it more easily if that ever comes up.

also note that I changed the naming convention slightly; you are welcome to format keys however you want but I went with keys like *plan_title* instead of *PlanIt Title* and *sender_id* and *user_id* instead of senderId and userId. My practice is for actual firebase keys I use all lowercase, underscore instead of spaces, and in code, I use lower/uppercase with no spaces. So if you copy paste my code, you'll need to change those.

Comment: Thanks @jay that was the correct solution. I can see where my mismatches were now. As far as the note you left - i definitely agree with your assumption, and i will need to query it to delete or modify the node frequently. So that would just be a bool there instead of a child by auto ID? Is that why the "uid_x: true" is there? Thanks for the insight also, it is very appreciated.

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Glad it helped! Restructuring the people_on_planit node is pretty cool as you can get to the data with no query since you know the path; the bool true acts as a placholder. For example you wanted to see if uid_y was in the people_on_planit node you can observingSingleEvent on */planit_node/people_on_planit/uid_y* and if snapshot.exists == true, that uid is in that node. Also, if you want to get a list of users you can just read that the people_on_planit node and iterate over the child nodes, fetching each key (the uid) which can then be used to look up each user.

Comment: Oh nice! That will save me a lot of future headaches. Im going to restructure my Firebase to match that. This is how i pushed my data to Firebase -  So instead of that dictionary at the end, i can just replace with a bool? Or am i missing a step or two _REF_PLANITS.child(withKeyOfPlanit).child("people_on_planit").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["user" : userKey])

Comment: when i say bool, i mean ([userKey: true]) - user key being that persons UID

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Dont use childByAutoId on the people_on_planit node in this case. It's perfect for creating parent child nodes to help disassociate child data from their parent but it's the wrong choice here. Do this *_REF_PLANITS.child(withKeyOfPlanit).child("people_on_planit").child(uid).setValue(true)* and if you want to remove it *_REF_PLANITS.child(withKeyOfPlanit).child("people_on_planit").child(uid).removeValue()* with *uid* being the users uid you want to add or remove fromt that node.

Comment: Got it, works like a charm. Things are starting to click now, it makes sense why i didn't want the auto id there in that case. Thanks

Comment: Hey @jay, setValue is only meant for having 1 node there though isn't it ? For instance, now a user wouldn't be able to add more than one person, because it seems that the setValue will just replace the existing node, rather than appending a new one

Comment: *ref.child("uid_0").setValue(true)* and then *ref.child("uid_1").setValue(true)* would result in whatever ref is, having two child nodes, both with the values set to true. If you did *ref.setValue(true)* that would overwrite ref but you're not doing that - you are setting a *child* of ref, in this case a users uid, to true.

Comment: Ok, wait just to get this clearly understood; I need to set two ref.child(“uid_0) & (“uid_1”) .setValue(true) ? Or not. Because in my app, ideally the user should be able to add as many people as they’d like. So I’m not sure if this would be hard coding or not. & I’m sorry for the repeated questions, SQL was so much easier to grip then Firebase.

Comment: I was using that to demonstrate how to add two child nodes, showing they don't overwrite each other. Each user would add a child node using that code. *ref.child(this users uid).setValue(true)*. If 100 users ran that line of code there would be 100 child nodes in *ref*

Comment: Understood perfectly! Man, you should seriously think about doing video tutorials, or Udemy or online teaching if you dont already.. I'd definitely subscribe and even go as far as paying for material. Its not easy to break complex things down through text, you do a great job of simplifying things through this medium, so I can only imagine through audio/video how great it would be! Thanks for the assistance..